# Use only the 5 higher values in amCharts pie?

Tags: json, amcharts

My data call can have lots of small elements (in percentage) that I would like to ignore, I only need the top 5 in my amCharts pie.

Can this be accomplished with amCharts or I should treat the data before?

please see my [jsfiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/pbarros/xznxbnc7/3/
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`hideLabelsPercent` property](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#hideLabelsPercent) to set a threshold for the lowest allowed percentage you want a label for. If you want to do this dynamically, you can set this in the `init` event by finding the 5th largest [`percents`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Slice#percents) value in the chart's [`chartData` array](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#chartData) and use it as your `hideLabelsPercent` threshold.  I've updated your handleInit method to do this:

```
function handleInit(e) {
  if (e.chart.chartData.length > 5) {
    //sort the copy of the chartData array from largest to smallest
    //if your data is pre-sorted, then you can skip this step
    var sortedData = e.chart.chartData.slice().sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
      return rhs.percents - lhs.percents;
    });

    //set the threshold equal to the 5th largest slice's percents value so that the rest are hidden
    e.chart.hideLabelsPercent = sortedData[4].percents;

    //redraw the chart
    e.chart.validateNow();
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xznxbnc7/9/

**Edit since I misread the question**

If you only want to show the top five slices from your dataset, you can filter on your backend or use the init method to sort and modify your dataProvider to contain only the top five.

```
function handleInit(e) {
  if (e.chart.chartData.length > 5) {
    //sort the copy of the chartData array from largest to smallest
    //if your data is pre-sorted, then you can skip this step
    var sortedData = e.chart.dataProvider.slice().sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
      return rhs[e.chart.valueField] - lhs[e.chart.valueField];
    });

    //only put in the top 5.
    e.chart.dataProvider = sortedData.slice(0, 5);

    // redraw the chart
    e.chart.validateData();
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3cchyjg/1

Comment: Thank you so much..but that really half way because you actually see the slices, I guess it's a better option for me to do a ajax call and select de data before makeChart

Comment: @PauloB - Ah, I misunderstood that you wanted to only display five slices. I updated my answer to handle that case as well.

Comment: yeah, that was really what I needed!